# Can we apply Reactjs and Jquery together on HTML DOM element

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am pretty new in `ReactJS` . I have created a DOM element using `reactJS` `JSX`

```
var Button = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div><button className="btn btn-primary" id="viewThis"> View This</button></div>
    },          
});
```

Now I want to apply some `jquery` stuffs on that element based on some event for eg :

```
$("#viewThis").click(function()  {
   //Code goes here
})
```

If this is doable. For some reason my `jquery` code is not working.

Comment: reactjs and jquery are basically javascript libraries so yes :)

Comment: you need to delegate that click event

Comment: Ok any reason that piece of code is not working , anything I am missing in `react`  part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to bind a click handler to a dynamically generated element. While you can get around this:

[Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

```js
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <button className="btn btn-primary" id="viewThis"> View This</button>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));

$('#app').on('click', '#viewThis', () => console.log('clicked'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You probably just want to use `onClick` in the component:

```js
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() =>console.log('clicked')}> View This</button>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Make perfect sense . Thanks a lot.